# Converting assembly function to c

Tags: assembly, decompilation

I have the following function in assembly, and i'm trying to convert it to c.

the function accept 2 parameters, the first one is `char*` and the second is the `int`

this is the assembly code:

```
71D3C400     PUSH EBP
71D3C401     MOV EBP,ESP
71D3C403     SUB ESP,8
71D3C406     MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8],0
71D3C40D     MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4],0
71D3C414     JMP SHORT 71D3C41F                       ; 71D3C41F
71D3C416     MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]
71D3C419     ADD EAX,1
71D3C41C     MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4],EAX
71D3C41F     MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]
71D3C422     CMP ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+C]
71D3C425     JNB SHORT 71D3C46B                       ; 71D3C46B
71D3C427     MOV EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
71D3C42A     ADD EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]
71D3C42D     MOVZX EAX,BYTE PTR DS:[EDX]
71D3C430     CMP EAX,0D
71D3C433     JE SHORT 71D3C443                        ; 71D3C443
71D3C435     MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
71D3C438     ADD ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]
71D3C43B     MOVZX EDX,BYTE PTR DS:[ECX]
71D3C43E     CMP EDX,0A
71D3C441     JNZ SHORT 71D3C445                       ; 71D3C445
71D3C443     JMP SHORT 71D3C416                       ; 71D3C416
71D3C445     MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
71D3C448     ADD EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]
71D3C44B     MOVZX ECX,BYTE PTR DS:[EAX]
71D3C44E     ADD ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8]
71D3C451     MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8],ECX
71D3C454     MOV EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8]
71D3C457     SHL EDX,1
71D3C459     MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8]
71D3C45C     AND EAX,80000000
71D3C461     SHR EAX,1F
71D3C464     OR EDX,EAX
71D3C466     MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8],EDX
71D3C469     JMP SHORT 71D3C416                       ; 71D3C416
71D3C46B     MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8]
71D3C46E     MOV ESP,EBP
71D3C470     POP EBP
71D3C471     RETN
```

and this is my c code until now:

```
_71D3C400 (char*str, int len) {
    int var1 = 0; // [EBP-8]
    int var2 = 0; // [EBP-4]

    goto _71D3C41F;

_71D3C416:
    var2++;

_71D3C41F:
    ECX = [EBP-4];

71D3C422     CMP ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+C]
71D3C425     JNB SHORT 71D3C46B                       ; 71D3C46B
    if (str[var2] == 0x0D) {
        goto _71D3C443;
    }

    if (str[var2] != 0x0A) {
        goto _71D3C445;
    }

_71D3C443:
    goto _71D3C416;

_71D3C445:
    var1 = str[var2] + var1;
    var1 = (var1 << 1) | ((var1 & 0x80000000) >> 0x1F);
    goto _71D3C416;

_71D3C46B:
    return var1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code may look like this:

```
int someFunction (char*str, int len) {
    int var1 = 0, var2 = 0;

    while (var2 <= len) {
        if (str[var2] != '\r' && str[var2] != '\n') {
            var1 = str[var2] + var1;
            var1 = (var1 << 1) | ((var1 & 0x80000000) >> 0x1F);
        }

        var2++;
    }

    return var1;
}
```

You could also rewrite it using for loop `for(var2=0;var2<len;var2++)`